# The older the Linux kernel is, the more secure?

Tags: linux, vulnerability, kernel

Are there security benefits running Linux Distro base on an older version of Linux kernel?

Security benefits = fewer vulnerabilities that can be exploited by hackers.

Linux Distro base on older version = RHEL-CENTOS that is running on kernel 3.10.  Compare to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS kernel version 4.15.

Comment: duplicate? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189509/what-kernel-is-more-secure

Comment: Did you mean to say that older kernels have *fewer* vulnerabilities?

Comment: @schroeder yes.

Comment: @justlinx69 Can you explain that further ... because it completely goes against common wisdom to always apply security patches immediately.

Comment: My interpretation of this question is "is a distro that uses an old kernel, but still receiving security patches more secure than a system that uses a newer kernel also receiving security patches?" Or are you really trying to compare a kernel that doesn't receive patches to one that does?

Comment: @ Mike Ounsworth @ tlng05  RHEL 7.5 use 3.10 linux kernel  and they patch the disto, i won't download some old 2005 disro and use it. i mean disro base Redhat but free like centos

Comment: Make Privilege Escalation Great Again. Use old kernel version, make bad boy's life easier

Comment: Centos and Ubuntu is apples to oranges in this context. Distributions have different default configurations. Also, beware that the decision by Ubuntu to allow unprivileged users to create namespaces SIGNIFICANTLY skews exploitable kernel vulnerability statistics. I can’t emphasize this enough. Tens of thousands of lines of kernel code, previously thought to be exposed only to privileged users (root) suddenly became accessible to all users. Much of it was soft, because auditing it seemed pointless - before containers, nobody cared if root could crash the kernel…

Comment: Regarding the attack surface exposed by unprivileged namespace creation: it can be turned off very easily with very basic hardening, which is why I consider it to be skewing the numbers

Answer (score 3):

Two major factors in the likelihood of open vulnerabilities are the frequency of changes, and time to discover vulnerabilities (and develop them into exploits).

While a version under active development is more likely to introduce a new vulnerability... and old version has had more time for attackers to analyze the source and create new exploits. It’s a bit of a balancing act.

Also consider that newer versions may have introduced stronger security barriers that are not present in older versions at all.

And when an vulnerability is found, it’s usually patched first in the latest version and then back-ported to the older versions. So time to fix is usually a bit faster on the new versions (we definitely saw this with Meltdown in Debian, where Debian 9 got a patch almost immediately, and it was weeks before it was back-ported to Debian 8).